# Python: Get column name by non zero value in row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have 10 rows and 3 columns. Each row has only one non zero value, which location by column differs between any row.

How can I iterate over each row, check if any non zero value exists, check its column index, and get (store in memory) the appropriate column name?

I tried a couple of approaches using the pandas library, but didn't find any short way.

Raw data:

```
index  A  B    C  D                 
11     0  3    0  0     
136    0  0    0  1     
186    0  0  184  0     
258    0  0   15  0     
455    0  1    0  0     
628    0  0    1  0    
774    0  0    2  0     
829    0  0    1  0     
1004   0  0  113  0     
1008   0  0    1  0
```

Example of one of the expected outputs for 3 different indexes (136, 455, 1008):

```
['D', 'B', 'C']
```

Of course the output could be anything else like list of lists. But this case specific example is enough for me.

Found that:

```
empty_list = []    
memory_var = [empty_list.append(row.sort_values().max()) for row in 
             df.itterows()]
print(memory_var)
```

This helps me to make a list with only the highest values of each row. Now, I need to get *column names* of those values. Using "idxmax()" method returns an error:

```
'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'idxmax'
```

**Update:**

Found the correct solution for my case. The extraction of a specific column could be done by:

```
row[:].sort_values().idxmax()
```

Comment: So you want the row number and column name for all non-zeros values in your data?

Comment: No. I want only the column`s name. The navigation to the name of the column is based on any non zero value that exists in the specific row that is checked.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. So we are looking for the columns that don't have all zeroes?

Comment: Yes. Like iterating over rows in DataFrame object, checking if there is non zero value, appending the column`s name that corresponds to the values position in row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`idxmax` is perfect for this.  Original data includes Column D, so I used it, too:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''index  A  B    C  D                 
11     0  3    0  0     
136    0  0    0  1     
186    0  0  184  0     
258    0  0   15  0     
455    0  1    0  0     
628    0  0    1  0    
774    0  0    2  0     
829    0  0    1  0     
1004   0  0  113  0     
1008   0  0    1  0   
'''
df = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
        .set_index('index'))
```

```
# apply idxmax and show result
df['col'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), axis=1)
print(df)

       A  B    C  D col
index                  
11     0  3    0  0   B
136    0  0    0  1   D
186    0  0  184  0   C
258    0  0   15  0   C
455    0  1    0  0   B
628    0  0    1  0   C
774    0  0    2  0   C
829    0  0    1  0   C
1004   0  0  113  0   C
1008   0  0    1  0   C
```

Comment: This one is more helpful, but still not what i was looking for. Is there an option to apply by lambda only to specific rows and cast the resulted column names as a list?

Comment: I manipulated your suggested answer and got the expected output by using ".idxmax()". Because it was the closest answer to my question, ill mark as "accepted answer". Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> a_df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,0,0,0], "b":[0,3,0,0], "c":[0,0,0,7], "d":[0,0,0,0]})
>>> a_df
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  3  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  7  0

>>> a_df = a_df.replace(0, np.nan)
>>> a_df
     a    b    c   d
0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
1  NaN  3.0  NaN NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
3  NaN  NaN  7.0 NaN

>>> a_df.dropna(how="all", axis=1).columns.tolist()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

If you want to preserve the orginal df:

```
>>> a_df.replace(0, np.nan).dropna(how="all", axis=1).columns.tolist()
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> a_df
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  3  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  7  0
```

Comment: This is great and helpfull. But, doing the same and avoiding the .dropna() method will be more helpfull. The reason is to preserve the original df as is. In order to precise my question, is it possible to cast it only on one, randomly(or not) chosen, row?

Comment: Updated the answer to keep the orignal df intact. If you want to perform the operation on a subset of the df you can slice by `a_df[:1]`, this will only keep the first 1 row.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. And yet, this is not as specific as im looking for. The expected output should be per se, hence using ".dropna()" and ".tolist()" doesnt help me achieve the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach that ends up adding a column at the end of the original DataFrame containing the non-zero column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [ 0,0,9],'y' : [-1,0,0],'z' : [0,1.1,0]},index=['a','b','c'])
df["non_zero_columns"] = df.where(df == 0, 
                                  other=df.apply(lambda x: x.name), 
                                  axis=1).where(df != 0, 
                                                other="").apply(lambda row: ''.join(row.values), axis=1)
```

'df' is now:

```
    x   y   z   non_zero_columns
a   0   -1  0.0 y
b   0   0   1.1 z
c   9   0   0.0 x
```

Breaking apart the one-liner, the two where() calls set zeros to empty strings and non-zero values to the name of the column they're in.  These values (empty strings and column names) are string concatenated in the apply() to create the "non_zero_columns" column.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately this not helps me a lot. I need something more case specific, store it in outter variable (and not in the df itself as a new column), and less cosmetic if possible. Some brains here posted using the "idxmax()" which is the closest one to the expected output. Yet, its not there.

Comment: No worries. You can always pull the column to a separate variable, e.g: `non_zero_columns = df["non_zero_columns"].to_dict()` or `to_list` depending on what you want.  

Frankly, don't know what 'less cosmetic' means, so I can't help there.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the apply function of DF.

Iterate over the row and check at which index of the row the non-zero value is present. To get the column name use the df.columns.

```
data = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0], [3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4], [0, 5, 0], [6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 7], [0, 8, 0], [9, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b", "c"])

df["d"] = df.apply(lambda row: df.columns[[i for i in range(len(row)) if row[i] > 0][0]], axis=1)

   a  b   c  d
0  0  0   1  c
1  0  2   0  b
2  3  0   0  a
3  0  0   4  c
4  0  5   0  b
5  6  0   0  a
6  0  0   7  c
7  0  8   0  b
8  9  0   0  a
9  0  0  10  c
```

Update:
To get the names of the columns with non-zero values:

```
column_list = df["d"].tolist()
['c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

To only get the names of the columns at the specific locations:

```
df["d"].iloc[[1, 3, 5, 7]].tolist()
['b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: I need it to be case specific. Suppose i only want to get the column name only for number 7 in row 6. The same if i want to extract only the column names, as a new list object.

Comment: Above code fulfills your requirements as mentioned in the question. Can you please elaborate with sample input and the expected output?

Comment: The answer has been updated with the output. Please accept the solution if it solves your problem.

Comment: Updated the question. Im sorry but its not solving the question for me. I need it to be case specific, so that data manipulation should be as minimal as possible. Meaning that i dont want to make another column, and the extraction of the column name should be based only by value in row that is checked.